# Convert from innodb to MyISAM for fulltext

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, innodb, myisam

I want to use `fulltext` in a big table, and I can't update mysql for support `fulltext` in `innodb` or use external search engine.

So I think I have 2 option here.

1.Using `innodb` and search database with `LIKE`

2.Convert my table to `MyISAM`

I don't know what is the best way and need help for this.

Comment: Exactly my question and a helpful answer. Can't imagine why you got a downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 3 is better: Upgrade to MySQL 5.6 where [`FULLTEXT` indexes are supported on InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html).

If you can't do this you're really asking for trouble.

Using #1 is futile, it won't scale beyond even the most trivial sized databases.

Going with #2 is a bad call, MyISAM is a notoriously troublesome database engine that doesn't support transactions or journaling. Data integrity is always *approximate* and a server crash can scramble your database into an unusable state since there's no transaction journal for recovery and streaming replication isn't an option.

The alternative is to use an add-on searching tool like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/02/07/use-sphinx-with-mysql/). If this is a no-go you're really going to have to re-evaluate your constraints.

Honestly, upgrading to MySQL 5.6 is as seamless as it gets. Most in-place upgrades work flawlessly.

Comment: It's a share server and I have no access for upgrade, i can't find answer, in my situation what is the best way i should do

Comment: Your answer is to find a different hosting provider. MySQL 5.6 was released in stable form over two years ago. There's no excuse for them to be trailing behind so badly. If they can't be bothered to patch their database server, who knows how many outstanding security patches there are.